# Member Since Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

On my profile and profiles I visit the Member Since looks incorrect:

{ Member since today } else { Member for 3 years, 7 months }

[image: profile bug]

Is this intentional? I can see it in the latest version of Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @Oded the speed! :P

Comment: @Tim - I screw up, I fix up. Fast ;)

Comment: It was already fixed (code-wise) when you posted this report, waiting to be deployed. @Oded cheated. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard He was waiting until someone noticed to show off his speed :P

Comment: I thought I'd gone mad when I refreshed the page and it was gone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Noticed a few minutes ago.

Fixed and deployed network-wide a few seconds ago...

Comment: Good stuff! I'll mark it answered when the timer is done.